# Sed line when matching some string and not another one with sed

Tags: linux, sed

Struggling again.

I would like to add a line right after another one when matching some pattern and not a another one.

Here's my input file :

```
# abc def hello
# bye hello zzzz
# abc def hello
```

Expected output is :

```
# abc def hello
new line
# bye hello zzzz
# abc def hello
new line
```

I want to add a line after any line of a file that starts with **#**, contains the word **hello** but not **bye**

I read about some exclusion possibility with sed (i.e `\*<kbd>/pattern/!</kbd> \*`) but haven't managed to add it to command so far.

Thanks!

```
sed -e '/^#.\*hello.\*/Ia\\'"new line" $input_file
```

where can the ***/bye/!*** thingy be included to this?

Comment: `llo.*/Ia\'"n` What is the `I` doing there? Ach `The I modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which causes the regexp to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. `

Comment: Well that's it actually. 
Sorry for not having pointed out that i need a case insensitive behaviour.

Comment: sed is great for doing s/old/new on individual lines but for anything else just use awk for clarity, simplicity, robustness, portability, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where can the /bye/! thingy be included to this?

Sed is a programming language, technically. Start a block and check within.

The real issue is that `a` reads the whole next line. So you have to like start another one to close `}`.

```
sed -e '/^#.*hello.*/I{ /bye/!a\' -e "new line" -e '}' "$input_file"
```

The syntax of `a` command is:

```
a\
text
```

Technically, there has to be newline in the sed script for text. I see `a\text` works anyway, but technically it is not valid. GNU sed also allows for just `a text`.

Prefer to quote variable expansion in shell. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: `a\text` doesn't work in bsd sed. so possibly not in macos either.

Comment: Thanks KamikCuk. 
It works like a charm. Just added the case insensitive option :

`sed -e '/^#.*hello.*/I { /bye/I! a\' -e "new line" -e '}' "$input_file"`

Answer (score 2):

sed solution just needs braces:

```
sed '
    /^#/ {
        /hello/ {
            /bye/!a\
new line
        }
    }
' input_file >output_file
```

It's a bit cleaner with awk:

```
awk '
    1;
    /^#/ && /hello/ && !/bye/ { print "new line" }
' input_file >output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/bye/b;/^#.*hello/a\new line' file
```

If a line contains `bye` we are not interested so bail out.

If a line begins `#` and then contains `hello` add a line containing `new line`.